# Check row by row and highlight mismatches in row/column when it occurred

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr

I have a data frame with 3 months of data with individual information. Individual information must be fixed during the whole period, however, in my real data set it is not the case. I would like to check row by row and highlight the dates that something went wrong during data entry.

Here is sample of my dataset ( real dataset has more variables):

```
input <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
             date = c(20190218, 20190219, 20190220, 20190221, 20190222,
                      20190223, 20190101, 20190103, 20190105, 20190110,
                      20190112, 20190218, 20190219, 20190220, 20190221, 20190222,
                      20190223),
               id = c("18105265-ab", "18105265-ab", "18105265-ab",
                      "18105265-ab", "18105265-ab", "18105265-ab",
                      "18161665-aa", "18161665-aa", "18161665-aa", "18161665-aa",
                      "18161665-aa", "18502020-aa", "18502020-aa", "18502020-aa",
                      "18502020-aa", "18502020-aa", "18502020-aa"),
             size = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1),
      type = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2),
           county = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
    member_p10 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1),
     youngest_age = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7),
              sex = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
   position = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0))
```

Is there any way for this type of operation? I would like to have this output at the end:

```
      date          id size type county member_p10 youngest_age sex position
1 20190221 18105265-ab    3    4      1          3            5   1        5
2 20190222 18105265-ab    2    4      1          2            7   1        5
3 20190105 18161665-aa    2    4      1          2            7   2        4
4 20190110 18161665-aa    1    2      1          1            7   2        0
5 20190221 18502020-aa    2    4      5          2            7   1        3
6 20190222 18502020-aa    1    2      5          1            7   1        0
```

Comment: "Individual information must be fixed during the whole period, however, in my real data set it is not the case." I don't know what you mean by this. How is it that you determine there's a mistake?

Comment: Sorry, If I was not clear enough. For example we have an individual that gender switched from male to female (same id) after couple of days or household type (type variable) switched from 4 members to 6 members. Let's assume demo shouldn't suddenly change, My aim is to highlight these change here

Comment: In your dataframe, rows 5 and 6 have the same info but the only difference is one has `date` equal to `20190222` and the other has it equal to `20190223`. In your example output, you chose to output only the row that has `20190222`. Is there a particular reason for that, or would outputting the other row have worked as well?

Comment: No, no particular reason, the mismatch occurred between 20190221 and 20190222. I just wanted to highlight that , lets say from that date the demo has change